# Else if statement changing array item to undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

So this is really weird and I am totally lost as to why this is happening. I am building a webapp in Node.js that takes .csv files, parses them, and then inserts them into a MySQL database. Here is the function up to the point its having the issue:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
var appVars = require('../../../../libs/Worker');
var dataObj = require('../../libs/DataPass');
var frequents = require('../../libs/FrequentCalls');
var queryScript = require('../../../../libs/QueryExecute');

/*** POST ***/
router.post('/', add_mass_changes); 

async function add_mass_changes(req, res) {
  var user_login = req.login;
  var msg = '';
  var mass_changes = {};
  var location = req.location;
  if(req.files.file === undefined) {
    var fileSize = 0;
  }
  else {
    var fileSize = req.files.file.size;
  };

  if(fileSize > 0) {
    var data = req.files.file.data.toString('utf8');
    var lineArray = data.split('\r\n');
    var addMassChangesArray = [];
    if(lineArray[0].indexOf('login') === 0) {
      for(var i=1; i<lineArray.length; i++) {
        if(lineArray[i].trim() === "") {
          var clean = lineArray[i]
            .split('"')
            .map(function(v,i){ return i%2===0 ? v : v.replace(/,/g,''); })
            .join('"')
            .replace(/"/g, '');

          //Split by actual csv comma
          dataSplit = clean.split(',');

          if(dataSplit[1] === '') { //check to ensure effective_date is set
            var msg = 'effective_date column was left blank. Please fill it in and try again.';
            mass_changes = await frequents.getMassChanges(location, req);
            res.render('mass_changes',{'mass_changes': mass_changes, 'msg':msg, 'user_login': user_login, csrfToken: req.session.csrfSecret});
            return
          }
          else if(dataSplit[7] !== 'Yes') {
            console.log(dataSplit[7])
            var msg = 'Column 8 must be Yes or No.';
            mass_changes = await frequents.getMassChanges(location, req);
            res.render('mass_changes',{'mass_changes': mass_changes, 'msg':msg, 'user_login': user_login, csrfToken: req.session.csrfSecret});
            return
          }

          else if(dataSplit[0].length) {
            if(dataSplit.length === 23) {
              addMassChangesArray.push ({
                'col1' : dataSplit[0],
                'col2' : dataSplit[1],
                'col3' : dataSplit[2],
                'col4' : dataSplit[3],
                'col5' : dataSplit[4],
                'col6' : dataSplit[5],
                'col7' : dataSplit[6],
                'col8' : dataSplit[7],
                'col9' : dataSplit[8],
                'col10' : dataSplit[9],
                'col11' : dataSplit[10],
                'col12' : dataSplit[11],
                'col13' : dataSplit[12],
                'col14' : dataSplit[13],
                'col15' : dataSplit[14],
                'col16' : dataSplit[15],
                'col17' : dataSplit[16],
                'col18' : dataSplit[17],
                'col19' : dataSplit[18],
                'col20' : dataSplit[19],
                'col21' : dataSplit[20],
                'col22' : dataSplit[21],
                'col23' : dataSplit[22],
                'col24' : user_login
              });
            }
            else {
              var msg = 'Incorrect columns. Please use the sample csv and try again.';
              mass_changes = await frequents.getMassChanges(location, req);
              res.render('mass_changes',{'mass_changes': mass_changes, 'msg':msg, 'user_login': user_login, csrfToken: req.session.csrfSecret});
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if(addMassChangesArray.length) {
        try {
          var msg = 'Success!';
          var action = 'Add Mass Changes';
          var table_name = 'mass_changes';

          add_mass_changes = await frequents.addMassChanges(req, addMassChangesArray);
          add_mass_changes = await frequents.addLog(req, action, table_name);
          mass_changes = await frequents.getMassChanges(location, req);
          res.render('mass_changes',{'mass_changes': mass_changes, 'msg':msg, 'user_login': user_login, csrfToken: req.session.csrfSecret});
        }
        catch(e) {
          var msg = e;
          mass_changes = await frequents.getMassChanges(location, req);
          res.render('mass_changes',{'mass_changes': mass_changes, 'msg':msg, 'user_login': user_login, csrfToken: req.session.csrfSecret});  
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      var msg = 'First column is not what the tool expects. Please use the sample csv and try again.';
      mass_changes = await frequents.getMassChanges(location, req);
      res.render('mass_changes',{'mass_changes': mass_changes, 'msg':msg, 'user_login': user_login, csrfToken: req.session.csrfSecret});
    }
  }
  else {
    var msg = 'No file... try that again.';
    mass_changes = await frequents.getMassChanges(location, req);
    res.render('mass_changes',{'mass_changes': mass_changes, 'msg':msg, 'user_login': user_login, csrfToken: req.session.csrfSecret});
  }
}; 

module.exports = router;
```

The issue comes when I am doing a check on one of the csv columns to make sure it contains a specific value.

```
else if(dataSplit[7] !== 'Yes') {
  console.log(dataSplit[7])
  var msg = 'Column 7 Must Be Yes or No.';
  mass_changes = await frequents.getMassChanges(location, req);
  res.render('mass_changes',{'mass_changes': mass_changes, 'msg':msg, 'user_login': user_login, csrfToken: req.session.csrfSecret});
  return
}
```

When the value in dataSplit[7] does not equal Yes, the console.log spits out the value i have in my .csv file. However, when the value does equal yes, it somehow is seeing it as undefined and this if statement still triggers, consoling out 'undefined'.

I am doing a similar check above, checking if a column is blank, and it is working

```
if(dataSplit[1] === '') {
  var msg = 'effective_date column was left blank. Please fill it in and try again.';
  mass_changes = await frequents.getMassChanges(location, req);
  res.render('mass_changes',{'mass_changes': mass_changes, 'msg':msg, 'user_login': user_login, csrfToken: req.session.csrfSecret});
  return
}
```

When I console.log(dataSplit) this is what I get:

```
[ 'abc2',
  '9/20/2018',
  'test',
  '',
  '1',
  '3',
  '1509',
  'Yes',
  '',
  '',
  'Reason',
  'Manager',
  '',
  '',
  'Y',
  'FT',
  '40',
  '',
  '',
  'CurrentLocation',
  'NewLocation',
  '9/16/2018',
  '9/22/2018' ]
[ '' ]
```

Why would my if statement turn dataSplit[7] into undefined when the if statement is true when it's false the value is fine? Tried to include what I thought was the relevant code/information.

Comment: If the console.log() statement is returning undefined than it makes since since undefined != 'yes'

Comment: But it only equals undefined when the value in my file matches 'Yes'. Any other value it consoles as the value, and not undefined.

Comment: If the value is equal to `Yes`, it would not go into that if statement....  So not sure how it would do anything...

Comment: It shouldn't go into the if statement, but it is.

Comment: Well what you are saying and what your code has says that is not possible. So you need to show more code and maybe working code that produces the error.

Comment: Are you sure the console log is coming from that `else if` block?

Comment: I am sure its coming from that else if block. Updated post to show more code.

Comment: You have two lines in the CSV. The first line is valid, the second line is empty, and `dataSplit = [""]`.

Comment: This is what I thought as well, however, I have confirmed the csv does not have an empty row. I've created new files and deleted all rows below the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're showing two lines being logged by `console.log(dataSplit)`. The first line has the expected 23 fields, but the second line is just an empty string. When you split the empty string, you get an array containing a single empty string, `['']`. Your problem is happening when you process the second line.

The first test `if (dataSplit[1] === '')` fails because there is no `dataSplit[1]`. Then it does `if (dataSplit[7] !== "Yes")`. Since there is no `dataSplit[7]`, its value is `undefined`. The test succeeds, and then it logs `undefined`.

You can just skip blank lines. At the top of the `for` loop, do:

```
if (lineArray[i].trim() === "") {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean but not 100% understanding the solution. I get I should put this in the for loop, but where exactly?

Comment: At the very beginning of the loop, right before `var clean = `

Comment: OK, that's what I thought but didn't seem to resolve it. I'm sure I didn't do it quite right... I've updated the first block of code on this question to contain the entire .js file with the changes made from your answer.

Comment: You have the condition backwards. You want to execute the rest of the code when the line is **not** empty, but you're only executing it when the line is empty.

Comment: Why didn't you just copy my code that uses `continue` to skip the rest of the loop body?

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood. I've copied the exact code you provided and worked like a charm. I for some reason understood the continue; as "this is where the rest of your code goes". It's been a long day...

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be the dataSplit[7] doesn't exist. Means the dataSplit length is less than 7 or value at dataSplit[7] is undefined.

when you are comparing undefined with 'Yes' it is true.

```js
dataSplit = ['yes'];
console.log("dataSplit[7]", dataSplit[7])
console.log( dataSplit[7] !== 'Yes')
```

Comment: Updated question to show the console.log(dataSplit). As you can see, the 8th value is Yes